# Can i make a "fullscreen" <pre>

Tags: html, css

I don't know how else to describe it, not fullscreen, but fill up the whole viewport.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>1001001</title>
  <style id="style-tag"></style>
  <script src="dist/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body spellcheck="false">
  <div id="content">
    <pre contenteditable id="style-text"></pre>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <a href="#" id="skip-animation">Skip</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

pre {
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 1px; /* Prevents bad clipping in Chrome. */
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 20px;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

**Expected outcome:**
The coloured block fills the entire screen (I require this to be a  as text is added afterwards).

**Actual outcome:**
Viewport is almost covered by the block, however, on the top and bottom, there is about 10px that are not coloured.

Comment: Full screen you mean by the whole screen removing the menu bar and address bar and not viewport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the css `min-height` property as `min-height:100vh;` (rather than 100%) on the `<pre>` element, that *should* solve your issue, by forcing the height of the element to at least the full viewport height.

Edit - also add `margin:0;` to the style of the `<pre>` element.  That seems to work for me.

Hope this helps! - James.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it only solved half my problem. It (kind of) fixed the white bar at the bottom, however now you can just scroll down to see the white bar. And nothing has changed with the top white bar.